# AOSP (native:ndk:libc++:shared) should not link to libutils (native:platform)

Tags: android-ndk, android-source

I am using a third-party SO library in AOSP, which is cross-compiled using NDK; It throws a few errors during the build.

> (native:ndk:libc++:shared) should not link to libutils (native:platform)

Here is my Android.mk:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/include \

LOCAL_LDFLAGS += $(LOCAL_PATH)/lib/libfastcdr.so \
    $(LOCAL_PATH)/lib/libfastrtps.so \
    $(LOCAL_PATH)/lib/libfoonathan_memory-0.7.1.so \
    $(LOCAL_PATH)/lib/libc++_shared.so

LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES += \
    liblog \
    libutils 

LOCAL_MODULE := ddsserver

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := \
        HelloWorldPublisher.cpp \
        HelloWorld_main.cpp \
        HelloWorldSubscriber.cpp
LOCAL_INIT_RC := ddsserver.rc

LOCAL_LDFLAGS += -Wl,--hash-style=both
LOCAL_CFLAGS := -Wno-error=non-virtual-dtor -fexceptions -Wno-unused-parameter

LOCAL_NDK_STL_VARIANT := c++_shared
LOCAL_SDK_VERSION := current
include $(BUILD_EXECUTABLE)
```

help help help me.